# primefaces calendar input text how to change

Tags: calendar, primefaces

I may customize input fields (change font, size, etc) in p:inputText, p:autocompelte, p:inputMask, but I have no idea how to change input text field for p:calendar.

Using .ui-datepicker-sth works fine for elements from the panel, but I can't find anything for changing input text field in p:calendar element.
Can anyone help me, pls?

Mi.

Comment: I was facing the same issue but it is resolved Please see answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62552381/9649057

Answer (score 9):

To change the width of the input field for the p:calendar, the following worked for me using Primefaces 5.1.

I defined this in the CSS file:

```
.calendarClass input {
    width: 50px !important
}
```

The p:calendar component style class is set as:

```
<p:calendar id="fromdate" styleClass="calendarClass" .../>
```

Answer (score 6):

To change the width of the input field for the p:calendar you can use

```
<p:calendar inputStyleClass="dateTimeField" .../>

.dateTimeField{
   width: 200px;
}
```

or

```
<p:calendar inputStyle="width:200px" .../>
```

or

```
<p:calendar styleClass="dateTimeField".../>

.dateTimeField input {
   width:200px;
}
```

https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=2610

Answer (score 4):

In this case, as @Matt indicates, you should overwrite the `ui-inputfield` class. For example, to remove the border radius or the shadow (the same with the focus):

```
.ui-inputfield {
    border-radius:0px;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

And then add your properties (border, font-size/weight...) to make the class to your liking.

Answer (score 4):

You can use size attribute directly for changing the size

Comment: Indeed the shortest and intended way, without new styleClasses.

Comment: For a general change of all `p:calendar` inputs, a _styleClass_ is better.

Answer (score 0):

The generated html for the Primefaces calendar input field looks like this (copied from the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/calendarBasic.jsf)):

```html
<input id="form:popupCal_input" name="form:popupCal_input" type="text" 
       class="ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all 
              hasDatepicker ui-state-hover" role="textbox"  ... >
```

So you need to adapt / overwrite one or more of the given classes to change the input field. Maybe you need to combine your css selector with the generated id to change the calendar input only and not all other input fields.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with `p:calendar` in inline mode:

CSS:

```
.calendar .ui-datepicker-inline{
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p:calendar styleClass="calendar" mode="inline" locale="pt_BR".../>
```