# How to modify the primeng p-calendar style?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to modify the primeng p-calendar, but it is not working properly.

For example:

I want it to be like this:[required changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBXoh.png)

But original it looks like this:[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVzvn.png)

What i have tried so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="nxui-form-group">
    <label for="planEndDate">
      <img src="assets/images/calendar.svg" class="nxui-icon-small nxui-icon-align-bottom">
      {{ 'i18n.all-damage-reports.label.plan-end-date' | translate }}
    </label>

    <p-calendar formControlName="planEndDate"
                class="calendar-control"
                id= "planEndDate"
                [title]="'i18n.all-damage-reports.label.plan-end-date' | translate"
                [dateFormat]="'i18n.common.dateformat.shortdate-p-calendar' | translate"
                [locale]="'i18n.common.dateformat.calendar' | translate"
    ></p-calendar>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
p-calendar.calendar-control  {
  opacity: 1;
  color: black;
  background: #eeeeee;
}
```

looking forward to inputs.

Thanks

Comment: can you please put up a working fiddle with the dependencies to play around?

Comment: @AllanJebaraj there are lot of dependency. But when we tried on the browser by changing the classes like ´.ui-widget.ui-state:disabled´, it worked fine. But same thing not working when we changed in our system.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you should use the special selectors of angular to change a component style like :host or ::ng-need, you can check that in the official documentation:

***https://angular.io/guide/component-styles***

```
::ng-deep body .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header .ui-datepicker-title {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 1;
color: goldenrod;
}

::ng-deep .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-group {
background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

Hope that'll help you !

Comment: this is exactly correct. In our case we use :host ::ng-deep

Also you can do it directly with <p-calendar [ngStyle={margin: 0}]> but that is super ugly....don't do that :)

Comment: ng-deep is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I want to style the calendar icon, html is below

```
<div class="main-container">
  <p-calendar showTime="true" hourFormat="12" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar>
</div>
```

Then I added style below but it is not working:

```
.main-container ::ng-deep .ui-datepicker-trigger.ui-button {
  // add style here
}
```

Then I added `p-calendar` after `::ng-deep` it worked

```
.main-container ::ng-deep p-calendar .ui-datepicker-trigger.ui-button {
  // add style here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the styling classes?
See https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar (section styling)

Like for example

```
.ui-calendar .ui-inputtext {
  // place text styling here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Select element class via using Inspect then add **::ng-deep** selector to force style on child components

```css
::ng-deep .ui-inputtext {
/* Example */
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me in changing the padding

```
::ng-deep .p-calendar .p-inputtext {
  padding: 2px 4px !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The code you see in the templates is not what actually is in browser's DOM. There are some other elements injected, like `<input>` for text input.

Try something like

```
p-calendar.calendar-control input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #eeeeee;
}
```

And anyway, look at the actual elements in your browser with Inspect Element and write CSS according to the real situation.

Comment: Actually there are lot of dependency classes, we tried to change all but not working. But when we change it in the browser directly for classes like ´.ui-widget.ui-state:disabled´, it's working perfect.

Comment: Applying your own styles to primeNg components is feasible but boring.